# Debugging create-react-app Build used for Unpacked Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app, source-maps

My current build process is to build the project with create-react app, then load the unpacked build as an extension. From there, I launch it, but when I do, I get an error in my main.[hash].js:formatted file.

Normally, I'd click on that error to go to the line number, drop a debugger, reload, and then figure out what's causing the problem. However, the file seems to not be source-mapped. I can't step through this code:

```
{
            key: "render",
            value: function() {
                var e = this
                  , t = this.state
                  , n = t.chromeVersion,
                  /// ... props, etc
                  , v = this.props.aProp,
                  , u = this.state.aStateVal,
                  , _ = Object(H.b)(this.state.anotherVal)
                return p.a.createElement("div", {
                // etc etc
```

which should instead look something like this:

```
render() {
    const {
      chromeVersion,
      // other state values
    } = this.state;
    const error = this.props.aProp
    const display = this.state.aStateVal,
    let getStuff = aFunction(
      this.state.anotherVal
    );

    return ( 
        <div /...
   // etc etc
```

my webpack.config.js at the base of the project looks like this:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
}

module.exports = {
  entry: `${__dirname}/src/index.js`,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/../build`,
    filename: "background.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app")]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // there used to be an uglify here, but I've removed it
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

I run my build with the following commands:

```
     GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true NODE_ENV=development react-scripts build 
     && webpack --config path/to/webpack.config.js 
     && node /path/to/prepareManifestForExtension.js  // Needed for chrome app
```

What am I missing to be able to debug my code when running my chrome app? How do I get error messages that point to the source mapped line?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AbnerZheng nope